# How to force artifact/module name with Gradle build

Tags: gradle

**Please note:** even though this question specifically mentions [Bamboo CI](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) and the [Gradle ShadowJar](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) plugin, I believe this is a basic Gradle config question at heart, and believe it can be answered by any battle-weary Gradle Guru.

I have a Groovy app that is built with Gradle, where `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

group = 'com.me.myapp'

mainClassName = "com.me.myapp.MyAppDriver"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Omitted for brevity
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

shadowJar {
    classifier = ''
    mergeServiceFiles {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives(file("${buildDir}/libs/myapp-${version}.jar")) {
        name "myapp"
        classifier ""
        builtBy shadowJar
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

And where `gradle.properties` is:

```
group=com.me.myapp
version=1.0.0
```

As you can see, I'm using ShadowJar to produce a self-contained "fat JAR" for my app. When I run `gradle clean build shadowJar` on my local machine, Gradle produces a `build/libs/myapp-1.0.0.jar` artifact/archive. However, when this same command is ran from our CI server (Bamboo), Gradle produces a `build/libs/MYAPP-KEY-1.0.0.jar` artifact/archive, where `MYAPP-KEY` is the Bamboo "*build key*" (essentially, a unique key/label identifying the build on the server). If you're clueless as to what I'm talking about, I don't think that really matters. What *is* important to understand is that Bamboo will check out the source code for `myapp` to a folder *named* `MYAPP-KEY` on the CI server. So locally `myapp/` is the root of my project, but on CI `MYAPP-KEY` is the root of my project.

**The main point is** that I am not explicitly defining *something* in my Gradle config, and so it seems that Gradle is using the name of the project root to produce the name of the built JAR. **What is this "something" and how/where do I define it?** The desired end objective is to produce a `build/libs/myapp-1.0.0.jar` both locally and on CI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please, look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

you can specify base name or full archive name of jar

add it to your `jar` section